# Add data to line chart using chart.js

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

I would like to add a new data in chart but the browser throws an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when calling to my "Add" function.

It seems that the chart object does not recognized the "AddData" function but I don't know how to solve it. In documentation appears this function it doesn't  work properly to me.

> .addData( valuesArray, label )
>   Calling addData(valuesArray, label) on your Chart instance passing an array of values for each dataset, along with a label for those points.

Fiddle sample
http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/pevy7vsz/5/

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

$("#add").on( "click", function() {
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var point = $("#point").val();
    var points = new Array();
    points.push(point);
    console.log("adding...");
    console.log("month:" + month);
    console.log("point:" + point);
    myLineChart.addData(points, month);
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it! And found that the version of the `Chart.js` you were used is `0.2.0`, but it doesn't has the `addData` method.

You should use the latest version, and try again, it should work!

http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js

Comment: You're right!
I just update sample and It works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/pevy7vsz/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for a line chart.

```
 var label_X = [0];
 var data_Y = [0];
 var line_chart;
var data = {
            labels: label_X,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Generations',
                data: data_Y,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(243, 187, 69, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };
        var options = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            }
        };
        var ctx = $("#line-chart").get(0);
        line_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
```

This was all the initializations then You need to make an ajax call to

```
 $.get("someurl", {
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {

                data_Y.push((response.Y_value));
                label_X.push(response.X_labels);
                line_chart.update();

            });
```